# Delete DataGridView line

Tags: .net, winforms

How can I delete a line form a bound `DataGridView` when pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key?

Comment: Need more information. What framework version? ASP.NET or Windows Forms?

Comment: The question is tagged winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on framework 3.5, it looks like there's a method on the DataGridView to process the delete key.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdeletekey.aspx

Otherwise, I would suggest capturing the form keypress event and working backwards to get the active/selected DataGridView row to know which one to process.